# How to build an array of arrays in a list grouped by a single field

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I have a table of many items with similar data like:

ItemDetails

```
id   name     value   item_id
1    Toy      10300   1
2    Toy2     10103   1
3    Title    One     1
4    Toy      300     2
5    Price    103     2
6    Exp      2020    2
```

I would like to use a find method using CakePHP 2.x that reads all the data and groups all the items in an array sorted by item_id value.  This is an array with each element containing an array of all the values that have the same item_id.  So the array looks like:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
     (
      [0] => Array
        (
            [ItemDetail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Toy
                    [value] => 10300
                    [item_id] => 1
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ItemDetail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Toy1
                    [value] => 103003
                    [item_id] => 1
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ItemDetail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [name] => Title
                    [value] => One
                    [item_id] => 1
                )
        )
   )
 [1] => Array
  (

    [0] => Array
        (
            [ItemDetail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [name] => Toy
                    [value] => 300
                    [item_id] => 2
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [ItemDetail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [name] => Price
                    [value] => 300
                    [item_id] => 2
                )


        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ItemDetail] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [name] => Exp
                    [value] => 2020
                    [item_id] => 2
                )
        )
    )
)
```

I've tried a few ideas with grouping, but it seems to wipe out all the field values except the first one it finds in the table.  I don't really want to aggregate the data, but group  everything with similar item_id's together in its own array.

Can someone point me in the right direction?  I would like to do this with one find statement so I can use paginate.  I've managed to do this with repeated finds with conditions=>id=(list of expected item_id) and build the array from the results of each call.  But there seems like there should be a better way.

Comment: you want to make a cakephp find method for this query "select * from itemdetails order by item_id" , correct me if im wrong

Comment: Basically.  The trick is I would like the results grouped in an array.  So array[0]=array(all elements with item_id=1), array[1]=array(all elments with item_id=2)...etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sql aggregation and group by won't really help to do what you want here.  What you would need to do is something along the lines of:

Order your sql result set by item_id in your query.

something like:

```
select id,
       name,
       value,
       item_id
from ItemDetails
order by item_id
```

step through the result set, keeping track of the previous item_id in a temporary variable.  When the current row's item_id doesn't match the previous, then it's time to start a new element of your outer array.

So, something like:

```
$temp_item_id = -1;
$i = -1;
$result = array();
foreach($statement->fetchRow() as $row) {
    if ($row['item_id'] !== $temp_item_id) {
        ++$i;
        $result[$i] = array();
    }
    $temp_item_id = $row['item_id'];
    $result[$i][] = array('ItemDetail' => $row);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned I'm already doing that to manually group them.  I'm looking for a single query that will join the elements together in a structure similar to what I've mentioned.  If you haven't used cakephp then you might not appreciate why.

Comment: There is no such query.  You could possibly simulate it with group_concat, however.  something like:

    select group_concat(id) as ids,
              group_concat(name) as names,
              group_concat(value) as values,
              item_id
    from ItemDetails
    group by item_id